# Continuity of certain projections in the weak topology.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I'd like to prove that:

> Given a Hilbert space H and S a closed subespace, $S \subseteq H$, the
>   projection $P_{S}:H \to S$ is continuous in the weak topology.

I have tried the following. Suppose $x_{n} \to x$ weakly. Then $\lim <x_{n},h> = <x,h>$ for every $h \in H$. It is enough to prove that then $\lim <P(x_{n}),h> = <P(x),h>$ for every $h \in H$.

It is true, in general, that continuity between two Banach spaces implies weak continuity between them, this fits the proof.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: I think it's easier (in the sense that the known details don't muddy the waters) to prove the more general fact, that if $T \colon X \to Y$ is a continuous linear map between Banach spaces (we can be far more general, in fact), then $T \colon X_w \to Y_w$ is also continuous, where $X_w$ is the space $X$ endowed with its weak topology, and similar for $Y_w$.

Comment: Well, $P(h)$ is just some fixed vector, so that since $x_n \to x$ weakly, $$\langle x_n, P(h) \rangle \to \langle x, P(h) \rangle = \langle P(x), h \rangle.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you mean that continuity in the norm of the space imply weak convergence? Where can I find a proof for that? Thank you.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić In the limit, Are you using the fact that the the inner product is continuous in the weak topology? How do I prove that? Thank you!

Comment: Continuity $T\colon (X,\lVert\cdot\rVert_X) \to (Y,\lVert\cdot\rVert_Y)$ indeed implies continuity $T\colon X_w \to Y_w$. A proof should be in any decent book on Functional Analysis, possibly as an exercise. It's straightforward, since we have the transpose/dual/adjoint of $T$, $T' \colon Y' \to X'$, and thus $T^{-1}(\{y : \lvert \mu(y)\rvert < \varepsilon\}) = \{x : \lvert \mu(Tx)\rvert < \varepsilon\} = \{ x : \lvert (T'\mu)(x)\rvert < \varepsilon\}$, so the preimages of weak neighbourhoods of $0$ in $Y$ are weak neighbourhoods of $0$ in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this is indeed true.

First, the projection onto a closed subspace is a linear and continuous map.

Second, a linear and continuous map between Banach spaces (or Hilbert spaces) is always weakly continuous.

Thus $P_S$ is continuous in the weak topology.